# Music player with a few specific requirements

Tags: software-recommendation, sound

I am looking for a music player with a few specific requirements:

1. Must have a search function that whittles down results as you type, searching the entire library.
2. Must start playing a song when double clicked, and not continue to another song when that song finishes.
3. Must be approachable and immediately usable by people completely unfamiliar with the program. I think this is mostly covered by the first two requirements being met.

---

I've tried many players but unfortunately every one has failed to meet at least one of the requirements.

Rhythmbox meets 1 and 3, but continues to the next search result after the song which was double clicked ends.

Banshee is basically the same as Rhythmbox. While it has an option to "Stop when finished" this cannot (as far as I can tell) be made the default when double clicking a song.

Audacious (as far as I can tell) fails at 1.

Muine meets requirements 1 and 2, but unfortunately I couldn't make the search dialog always shown like it is with Rhythmbox / Banshee which, despite its very simple interface, made Muine incomprehensible to people trying to use it for the first time.

Amarok I could not configure to meet requirement 1, but I think it's likely I was just missing something, and with its configurability I'm confident that I can set it up to meet requirements 2 and 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quodlibet whittles down results by search term, and when the order is set to One Song, it plays one song and stops. It's pretty simple on the surface, but it's got a bunch of plugins to extend its capabilities.

[image]

Comment: @jordan uggla The ubuntu package is ancient. I just installed [quodlibet-2.3](http://code.google.com/p/quodlibet/downloads/list) and it's LOADS better. However, did have to manually `rm /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/quodlibet` even after apt-get purging the old one.

Comment: You can get the latest stable Ubuntu (2.4 at time of writing) from this PPA:
https://launchpad.net/~lazka/+archive/ppa